# Distributed random variable

Tags: probability-distributions

I'm studying for an exam and I'm having trouble with this example.

Height of a given population is a distributed random variable with parameters $\mu_0 = 170cm$ and $\sigma = 15cm$

a) What is the probability that a randomly selected person's height is >190cm

b) What is the probability that a randomly selected person's height is [160, 190]

I don't know where to start. Your help us very appreciated!

Comment: You should figure out how many standard deviations and to figure out the z-score. Then, use a z-score chart to find the probability.

Comment: How to I get the St. Dev. from that?

Comment: The standard deviation is already given in the problem as 15cm.

Comment: @RK01 "use a z-score chart to find the probability" Sorry but I strongly doubt that one can do such a thing.

Comment: What do you call "a distributed random variable"? Is it "a normally distributed random variable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height seems to be normally distributed. Therefore the term for a) is

$P(X>190)=1-P(X<190)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \right)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{190-170}{15} \right)$

$\Phi(\cdot)$ is the function of the normal distribution. The values can be looked up [here](https://www.stat.tamu.edu/~lzhou/stat302/standardnormaltable.pdf). For example it is $\Phi(0.8)=0.97727$

And the term for b) it is

$P(160<X<190)=P(X<190)-P(X<160)=\Phi\left(\frac{190-170}{15} \right)-\Phi\left(\frac{160-170}{15} \right)$